# Python - How can I exclude lines from the same file in itertools.combinations using fileinput?

Tags: python, file-io, combinations, python-itertools

This is my first time using python. I have 4 .txt files containing lines with potential dictionary variations of the words 'circle', 'square', 'dot', and 'point'. For example,

```
circle
circlE
circl3
..
square
squarE
squar3
..
dot
doT
d0t
..
point
poinT
po1nt
```

I am trying to create another .txt file with all possible combinations of each of the lines from these 4 files. I have the following code which successfully creates all combinations:

```
import fileinput
from itertools import combinations
from contextlib import closing
with closing(fileinput.input(['circle.txt', 'square.txt', 'dot.txt', 'point.txt'])) as f:
    for w, x, y, z in combinations(f, 4):
          t = open("circlesquaredotpoint.txt", "a")
          t.write('{}{}{}{}'.format(w.rstrip('\n'), x.rstrip('\n'), y.rstrip('\n'), z.rstrip('\n'))+'\n')       
          t.close()
```

But it is too massive, because it is combining elements from the same file. These are the first few results:

```
circlecirclEcircl3circLe
circlecirclEcircl3circLE
circlecirclEcircl3circL3
```

I would like to exclude any combinations of lines from the same file so terms are not repeated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have items separated into distinct categories and would like to pick from each category then that is called product() not combinations(). For example,

```
import itertools as it

A = [1,2,3]
B = [4,5,6]

print(list(it.product(A,B)))
```

Not sure why you have your code that way. I might write it like this:

```
import itertools as it

filenames = ['circle.txt', 'square.txt', 'dot.txt', 'point.txt']
words     = [(word.strip() for word in open(f)) for f in filenames]
data      = (''.join(prod)+'\n' for prod in it.product(*words)])
open("circlesquaredotpoint.txt",'w').writelines(data)
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. I had to increase my page file to 200 GB to avoid MemoryError. Then I found the generated .txt file is about 10 GB. I underestimated how many results my input data would generate, and that is only for circlesquaredotpoint. I will need to create them for each order as well, but I think I have enough space. Will just take some time to generate each one.

Comment: I didn't realize you were working with large data, you should use iterators instead of explicitly loading all the data. This won't use any ram. I will update the answer.

Comment: Updated. It should now not need any ram. It will only load use and write with the data needed at each step of the calculation.